# Pokemon Emerald - Rayquaza flew away before Kyogre and Groudon

Tags: cheats, pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

In Pokemon Emerald I wall walked past the people blocking the entrance for Wallace, now Kyogre and Groudon are there and Steven is asking me to find Wallace but he's not there and neither is Rayqauza.

What should I do - I don't want to restart so do you know any codes?

Answer (score 6):

There aren't really any cheats that will help you progress; but your description of where you are stuck in the story is just vague enough that I suspect you have missed something and may need retrace your steps.

It sounds like you are somewhere in [Part 15](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Appendix:Emerald_walkthrough/Section_15) or [Part 16](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Appendix:Emerald_walkthrough/Section_16) of Bulbapedia's [walkthrough for Pokemon Emerald](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Appendix:Emerald_walkthrough).

1. Once Kyogre and Groudon start their battle, you need to head to the bit of land west (left) of the gym and talk to Steven, who will lead you to the Cave of Origin to find Wallace.
2. After talking with Wallace, he'll head off to unlock the Sky Pillar on Route 131. Head there and climb the tower. When you approach Rayquaza at the top, he'll fly off towards Sootopolis. Follow him back.
3. Rayquaza should end the fight between Groudon and Kyogre (you *may* need to be infront of the gym with the other NPCs).
4. There will be talking and rewards, and the final gym will be open for you to challenge.

Comment: I visited Wallace before the battle though and then did that. I was using wall walk

Comment: @MinecraftBoxGuy if you used codes like wall walk, you need to specify this in the question and when you used it. This would affect the answer, since it might have meant you missed earlier events like those that Trent identified

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry that my question was very vague. I don't play this game anymore so I'm fine leaving it as is. Thank you for replying!